# Failed to construct 'RTCSessionDescription': parameter 1 ('descriptionInitDict') is not an object

Tags: android, webrtc

I am trying to do conference call between Android and Web Application on Chrome. When Android sends the offer to the web application, I get the following error on chrome console:

Failed to construct 'RTCSessionDescription': parameter 1 ('descriptionInitDict') is not an object.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

On Android, I have code like this:

```
PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(listener, true, true,
    true, mEGLcontext);
```

This is how I create Peer Connection object:

```
this.pc = factory.createPeerConnection(RTCConfig.getIceServer(), RTCConfig.getMediaConstraints(), this);
```

RTCConfig.getMediaConstraints() function is defined as following:

```
public static MediaConstraints getMediaConstraints(){
   // Initialize PeerConnection
   MediaConstraints pcMediaConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
   pcMediaConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(
      "DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
   pcMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(
         "OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"));
   pcMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair(
         "OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"));

   return pcMediaConstraints;
}
```

and RTCConfig.getICEServer() function is defined as :

```
public static LinkedList<PeerConnection.IceServer> getIceServer(){ 
   // Initialize ICE server list
   LinkedList<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new LinkedList<PeerConnection.IceServer>();
   iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"));
   return iceServers;
}
```

On Web application, I create peer connection object in this way:

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(
{'iceServers': [
  createIceServer(isChrome
    ? 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    : 'stun:23.21.150.121', null, null)
]}, 
{optional: [ {"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true}]});
```

This is how Web Application handles the offer:

```
pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.sdp), function () {
  $log.debug('Setting remote description by offer');
  pc.createAnswer(function (sdp) {
    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp);
    socket.emit('msg', { by: currentId, to: data.by, sdp: sdp, type: 'answer' });
  }, function (e) {
    $log.error(e);
  });
}, function (e) {
  $log.error(e);
});
```

The conference call between web to web is working fine. It is not working when android sends the offer to the web application. Also when Web sends the offer to the android then onCreateSuccess(final SessionDescription sdp)of SdpObserver is not called.

I could not find the solution to this error on Internet. I could not understand what descriptionInitDict means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the type of data.sdp on the browser side? If it is a string, which I think it is based on the name you gave it, that's the problem. You should be passing an object with two attributes: `type` and `sdp`. Take a look at the official spec [here](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#widl-ctor-RTCSessionDescription--RTCSessionDescriptionInit-descriptionInitDict)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It is showing some progress now. Web is able to create answer for android now. Android is not able to create answer or generate candidates.

Comment: The problem was the sdp object was converted into string in my case in the signaling server. I just changed it to object type & the error went through. Once hurdle cleared.